# How I can use anchor tag href to open details data for my code?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to open details data obtained from php-mysql in a model box instead of a new html page. Currently it is opening in other html page but I want to add that in a model box.

Here is my current code:

```
<a class="btn btn-info"  href="details.php?view_id=<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" title="click for Details" onclick="details.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Show Details</a>
```

here it refers to details.php?view_id but model example found with id selector like bellow,

```
<a href="#openModal">Show Details</a>
  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
               <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <h2>Modal Box</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
```

How I can add **href="details.php?view_id="** instead of **#openModel** ??

I am new learner, please help.

Comment: you can put an iframe in the modal div that calls that information as the src attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp there are other ways too depending on what kind of control you want but this is simplest.

Comment: Thank you "Danimal" , Iframe will not work because href="details.php?view_id=" has a dynamic reference value based on image or link click.

Comment: I think they meant that you can dynamically set the src of the iframe using the information from the button that was clicked

Answer (score 0):

```js
function edit_m_id(str){
  var xhttp;
    document.getElementById("edit_con_tent").innerHTML = "<center>loading.......</center>";
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("edit_con_tent").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "edit_m_con.php?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
```

```html
<a href="#small-modal" onclick="edit_m_id('<?php echo $id_rand;?>')" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>

<div id="small-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

   
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <span id='edit_con_tent'></span>
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```